# Why I can't retrieve a database field havin "point" as data type using Hibernate5\Spring Data JPA into this Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a **Spring Boot** project and I am going crazy trying to correctly map a **point** field of a MySql DB (it is MariaDB but it is the same thing...).

To retrieve data I am using **Spring Data JPA** on **Hibernate 5**.

I have this accomodation table on my DB:

```
Field                           Type                            Null            Key             Default             Extra   
id                              bigint(20) unsigned             NO              PRI             NULL                auto_increment
user_id                         bigint(20) unsigned             NO              MUL             NULL    
accomodation_name               varchar(255)                    NO              NULL    
description                     text                            NO              NULL    
nation                          varchar(255)                    NO              NULL    
region                          varchar(255)                    NO              NULL    
province                        varchar(255)                    NO              NULL    
city                            varchar(255)                    NO              NULL    
geographical_position           point                           NO              NULL    
stars                           int(10)                         NO              NULL    
accomodation_typological_id     bigint(20) unsigned             YES             NULL    
accomodation_service_id         bigint(20) unsigned             YES             NULL    
phone                           varchar(255)                    YES             NULL    
mobile                          varchar(255)                    YES             NULL    
fax                             varchar(255)                    YES             NULL    
email                           varchar(255)                    YES             NULL    
time_stamp                      datetime                        YES             NULL
```

As you can see this table contain the field **geographical_position** having **point** as data type (beloning to MySql opengGIS implementation).

The previous table is mapped by this Accomodation class:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Yngve on 30/09/16.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "accomodation")
public class Accomodation implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    /*@ManyToOne
    private Users users;
    */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accomodation")
    private List<Room> rooms;

    @Column(name = "accomodation_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @Type(type="text")
    private String description;
    private String phone;
    private String mobile;
    private String fax;
    private String email;
    private Integer stars;

    @Column(name = "geographical_position", columnDefinition="Point")
    private Point location;


    public Accomodation(){

    }

    // GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

As you can see the previous point field on the table is mapped by this field on my Java class:

```
@Column(name = "geographical_position", columnDefinition="Point")
private Point location;
```

In the previous code snippet I have also inserted the import of the used implementation of Point is provided by (I found it on some tutorial):

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
```

But I am absolutly not sure that this is the correct class that have to be used.

This is my DAO class the implement the Spring Data JPA query (the query is generated by Spring Data JPA using the method signature):

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface AccomodationDAO extends JpaRepository<Accomodation, Long> {

    //@Query("FROM Accomodation WHERE id = :id")
    Accomodation findById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

The problem is that testing the previous DAO method using this **JUnuit** test method:

```
@Test
public void placeSearcherControllerTest() {
    System.out.println("placeSearcherControllerTest START");

    Accomodation accomodation = accomodationDAO.findById(6L);

    System.out.println("placeSearcherControllerTest END");
}
```

I obtain the following error message in the IntelliJ console:

```
Hibernate: select accomodati0_.id as id1_0_, accomodati0_.description as descript2_0_, accomodati0_.email as email3_0_, accomodati0_.fax as fax4_0_, accomodati0_.geographical_position as geograph5_0_, accomodati0_.mobile as mobile6_0_, accomodati0_.accomodation_name as accomoda7_0_, accomodati0_.phone as phone8_0_, accomodati0_.stars as stars9_0_ from accomodation accomodati0_ where accomodati0_.id=?

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.findById(Unknown Source)
    at com.betriuvis.controller.test.PlaceSearcherControllerTest.placeSearcherControllerTest(PlaceSearcherControllerTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
    ... 86 more
```

The problem is certainly caused by this mapping on the **Accomodation** class:

```
@Column(name = "geographical_position", columnDefinition="Point")
private Point location;
```

because if I delete this field from my entity class I have no exception and I correctly retrieve the **Accomodation** object (that not contains the location field).

Looking at the previous error output I can see that Hibernate generate this SQL query:

```
select accomodati0_.id as id1_0_, accomodati0_.description as descript2_0_, accomodati0_.email as email3_0_, accomodati0_.fax as fax4_0_, accomodati0_.geographical_position as geograph5_0_, accomodati0_.mobile as mobile6_0_, accomodati0_.accomodation_name as accomoda7_0_, accomodati0_.phone as phone8_0_, accomodati0_.stars as stars9_0_ from accomodation accomodati0_ where accomodati0_.id=6
```

that performed directly on my database I obtain the correct record. As content of the previous **point** field I can see this value **[GEOMETRY - 25 B]** (what means **25 B**?) that downloaded is a file named accomodation-**geographical_position.bin**.

Performing this other query on the DB:

```
select id, AsText(geographical_position) from accomodation where id = 6
```

I correctly obtatin the coordinates contained in my **geographical_position** field, infact this i the obtained query output:

```
id      AsText(geographical_position)
--------------------------------------
6       POINT(41.729086 12.278478)
```

So the data is correctly stored into the **geographical_position** having **point** as data type.

So the problem is related to the mapping of the **geographical_position** field to the **Point location** of my entity class.

Searching on stackoverflow it seems to me that the **org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize** exception something happing when Hibernate can't put the value of a field into a specific Java object so I am having some doubt related the **import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point** used class to map the **point** database field (maybe is this a class used on the old version of Hibrnate Spatial or something like this?)

Or maybe it could be a **Spring Boot** configuration problem, so I put here also my **appliction.properties** file representing my entire application configuration:

```
#No auth  protected
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=true
#Enable shutdown endpoint
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
logging.file=BeTriviusController.log
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

# Thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache:false


# DATABASE CONFIG ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/betriviustest
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update, validate)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Maybe it could be something related to the Hibernate Spatial configuration? (it seems me a litle strange because from what I know it is directly included into Hibernate 5 and it is no more an external project to add and configure).

Finnally this is my **pom.xml** file containing all the used libraries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>BeTriviusController</groupId>
    <artifactId>BeTriviusController</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <springboot.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    </properties>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
                <!--<version>4.0</version>-->
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So, what is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and correctly map the Point location of my entity class with the value on the geographical_position table field having point as data type?

Comment: Tried annotating the `Point` field with `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")`?

Comment: Also shouldn't the hibernate dialect should be `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatial5InnoDBDialect`?

Comment: @Mubin now I have tryied to add this line into my application.propertis file but I still obtain the same result. Line added:
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatial5InnoDBDiale‌​ct

Comment: @AndreaNobili I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Have you made any progress on this?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same issue and was able to come up with a solution. Since, as you originally pointed out the mysql function `ST_ASTEXT(column_name)` works perfectly, which implies the data is definitely stored correctly.

I took that realization and decided to build the solution on top of it. Here's a snippet from my `@Entity` now.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "formEntryData")
public class FormEntryData {

    ...

    @Formula("ST_ASTEXT(data_geo)")
    private String dataGeo;

    public Geometry getDataGeo() {
        try {
            WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
            return reader.read(dataGeo);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then what you need to do is setup your Jackson `ObjectMapper` so that the `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.*` (i.e., `Geometry`, `Point`, etc.) can be serialized as JSON.

To do this add this dependency to your dependency manager (I used maven):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bedatadriven</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you'll just need to wire it up with Spring Boot's Configuration mechanisms.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public JtsModule jtsModule() {
        return new JtsModule();
    }
}
```

And voila! You can now read geometry type from mysql and output the accepted [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format! Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem occurs while trying to serialize: phone, mobile, fax, email and stars. You should put @Column annotations over those fields.
For the location it should work:
@Column(columnDefinition = "geometry")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")

Comment: No, as you can read in m original post, removing the field having data type "point" the mapping works well and I can retrieve all the information

Comment: mmm I think that this is the "Hibernate way" and not the "JPA way", I tryied but now I obtain the following error message: 
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType". So I search into the "org.hibernate.spatial." external library and I discover that inside it I have not the GeometryType class but I have something called GeolatteGeometryType. Could be this one?

Comment: I don't think so, but try it. IMHO I will do this another way. I will implement model class of location and use @OneToOne in accomodation class.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Can you explain me in details your solution?

Comment: `public class MyLocation {

Comment: And what have to contains? Only the Point field?

Comment: `@Entity
@Table(name="location")
public class MyLocation{
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="ID_LOCATIOn)
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "longtitude")
 private double Longtitude;
 
 @Column(name="altitude")
 private double altitude;
 
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
 private Accomodation accomodation;
}`

remember to delete getter for accomodation field

in class accomodation
`
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "accomodation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private MyLocation location;
`

Comment: ok but in this way you are not using the Point GIS feature provided by MySql, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes You are right. But for me it has more cons. e.g it will work on any sql database, and it's easier to understand

Comment: ok but in this way I think that it is very complex impelement query to find POI into a specific range?

Comment: Using HQL it will be easy: "from accomodation where accomodation.location.logtitude < 'some_val' "

Comment: @yt61 - There is a reason why Hibernate Spatial came out. You are asking to reinvent the wheel now, that's not correct.

Comment: @AndreaNobili -  `I think that this is the "Hibernate way" and not the "JPA way"` - Spatial is not supported in JPA out of the box. You'll have to rely on specific extensions. For Hibernate, the Hibernate Spatial project provides ready to use spatial dialects and custom types.

Comment: @Mubin what do you exactly mean? What have I to do? Can you try to explain me it more in details? Tnx